# How can I set javascript from every module?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3

In

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\views\users

I have : create.blade.php, index.blade.php, edit.blade.php etc

create.blade.php is like this :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        ...
    </section>
    <div class="content">
      ...
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
           ...
        });  

    </script>
@endsection
```

index.blade.php is like this :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        ...
    </section>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            ...
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

And in another module, I also do it. I combine the view and javascript

I want to separate and tidy it up

So each module, it has a javascript file and it separate from the view

Where I create javascript file from every module and how can I call it from view?

Or maybe you can give better input?

Answer (score 0):

Put your shared code inside your layout file, so when you're extending it, it would be accessible by the views